# UILabel of a TableViewCell changes position on reloadData and onClick

Tags: ios, uilabel, tableview

I have a tableView inside my ViewController and every time i try to reloadData or click the cell. A specific label moves higher and stays there.

Before reload or click!:[image]

After reloadData or click a cell:
[image]

Any ideas what is going wrong?

I call read function to get all the data in the database and store them in the NSMutableArray siteTableObjectsArray.

```
 dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void){
    [self read:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                siteTableObjectsFinalArray = [siteTableObjectsArray copy];
                NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                                    initWithKey:@"work.title" ascending:YES];
                NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortDescriptor];
                siteTableObjectsFinalArray = [siteTableObjectsFinalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });

        }
    }];
});
```

I copy this array into another NSArray, ( i use two arrays for another reason) and use this array to populate the table as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
WorkCell *cell = (WorkCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WorkCell"];

SiteTableObject *obj = [siteTableObjectsFinalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Authors *currAuth = obj.author;
Works *currentWork = obj.work;

cell.authorLabel.text = currAuth.authorName;
cell.workLabel.text = currentWork.title;
NSString* cleanedString = [obj.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
cell.textLabel.text = cleanedString;


cell.caategoryLabel.text = [categoriesDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentWork.categoryID]];
cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentWork.date];
cell.moreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i more",obj.more];
return  cell;
```

}

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

}

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
WorkCell *cell = (WorkCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
currentIndexRow =indexPath.row;
SiteTableObject *clickedObject = [siteTableObjectsFinalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Works *clickedWork = clickedObject.work;
selectedWorkId = [clickedWork.workID intValue];
if ([cell.moreLabel.text isEqualToString:@"0 more"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"p" sender:self];
}else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"more" sender:self];
}
```

}

and then every time I call reloadData it comes to the same result either i have changed the siteTableObjectsFinalArray or not!

After digging in the code i found a notification in WorkCell.h:
"Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'textLabel' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property."

Comment: If you are using storyboards or xib files you you should check your constraints. You also should add more code related to your custom cell.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout then might be problem with your constraints

Comment: No i am not using AutoLayout. Any suggestion for my constraints?

Comment: There must be some layout code in your WorkCell code that is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution thanks to the notification i noticed!

I just had to add:

```
@synthesize textLabel in the WorkCell.m file
```